# How to remove black bars with ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I'm trying to remove black bars from a 637×478 video

[image]

here's what happens:

```
% ffmpeg -i sfu11.mp4 -vf "scale=ih*16/9:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1" -y out.mp4 
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sfu11.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 01:02:49.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 99.833000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 99.833000, end 701.818000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 701.818000, end 1213.746000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 1213.746000, end 1726.892000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1726.892000, end 2167.882000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 2167.882000, end 2816.430000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 2816.430000, end 3769.366000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, progressive), 708x478 [SAR 9:10 DAR 1593:1195], 544 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 341 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7f8630806e00] width not divisible by 2 (849x478)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x7f8630809d00] Qavg: 15927.165
[aac @ 0x7f8630809d00] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

However, the same flags work using `ffplay` but I get horizontal black bars instead.

```
% ffplay -i sfu11.mp4 -vf "scale=ih\*16/9:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1"
```

[image]

I also tried using the [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect:%7E:text=11.47-,cropdetect,-Auto%2Ddetect%20the) filter. It doesn't work and end up with the very same black bars while passing `-vf crop=...`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a pair of filters, [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) and [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop).

CropDetect will find where the black bars exist

Crop will remove them.

CropDetect will output every time it finds black edges in a video.

You would use ffprobe to determine the crop locations.  It will output a line line:

`[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 000001cfc21cf240] x1:1 x2:1279 y1:2 y2:693 w:1264 h:688 x:10 y:4 pts:94094 t:3.920583 crop=1264:688:10:4`

That last segment is the crop filter.

You can then apply that to a video with `-vf crop=1264:688:10:4`

If you don't want to go copying/pasting thru output, might I suggest a little scripting?

I've been building a PowerShell Module called [RoughDraft](https://github.com/StartAutomating/RoughDraft) that tries to make FFMpeg more approachable and discoverable.

On MacOS, you'd need to [install PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.2), then you can:

```
Install-Module RoughDraft -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Import-Module RoughDraft
```

PowerShell has this great thing called an object pipeline.  This allows us to return structured information from each step, rather than making each step parse input.

To crop a video, you should be able to use something like:

```
Get-Media -InputPath .\MyVideo.mp4 -CropDetect  |
    Select-Object -Property InputPath, CropExpression -Unique |
    Edit-Media -CropVideo
```

Going step by step:

1. `Get-Media -InputPath .\MyVideo.mp4 -CropDetect` finds all of the crop expressions.
2. `Select-Object -Property InputPath, CropExpression -Unique` picks out the input path and crop expression (if you have more than one, let me know)
3. `Edit-Media -CropVideo` takes that pipelined input and edits the input file with the cropexpression, creating .\MyVideo_Crop.mp4

Let me know if you have any problems, and hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried the crop approach and it doesn't work. I use `ffmpeg -i sfu11.mp4 -vf cropdetect,metadata=mode=print -f null -` which outputs a crop region `crop=704:464:2:8` which I pass using `-vf crop=...`. The black bars persist. The only approach that seems to work is the one I described in the question which only works for `ffplay`. The issue has something to do with the aspect ratio The black bars don't actually exist.

Comment: You might want to adjust the -CropDetectLimit (in RoughDraft), or limit (in raw ffmpeg).

Basically, what appears to be black isn't always #000000

Comment: what would be the possible `ffmpeg` way to do it in this case?

Comment: see above.  RoughDraft is primarily a wrapper of FFMpeg